# How can I get the destination URL using cURL when redirect on JS?

Tags: curl

How can I get the destination URL page in cURL after JS redirect? This code is worked correct:

```
$url = 'http://google.com'; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
$lastUrl = curl_exec($ch); 
$lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
echo "Original: $url <br>Final: $lastUrl";
exit;
```

but if use this URL https://www.industrialsafety.com/search_results_a/256.html?Search=brady+76801 Final URL is same, but it should be this https://www.industrialsafety.com/Brady-76801-Brady-GlobalMark2-Color-Cut-p/cc-76801by.htm

Answer (score 0):

Three choices:

1. Find a PHP JS interpreter extension
2. Use python with selenium
3. write a link translation routine in PHP to emulate the JS code below

   if(pathname.match('/search_results_a/256.html')){
                   $('.content').addClass('content_search');
                   $('.content_search>div').addClass('search_middle_content');
                   $('.search_middle_content>div:eq(0)').addClass('search_left_bar');
                   $('#content_area').addClass('search_content');
                   $('.search_content>div:eq(0)').addClass('main_search_content');